# Generator plugin doesn't render data

Tags: jekyll

I am writing  a jekyll plugin to render an alternative layout for my posts in category "portfolio". The files are generated in the partial folder but the data is not rendered. What am I doing wrong?

Generator:

```
module Jekyll
  class PartialGenerator < Generator
    def generate(site)
      site.categories['portfolio'].each do |post|
        site.pages <<  PartialPage.new(site, site.source, post)
      end
    end
  end

  class PartialPage < Page
    def initialize(site, base, post)
      @site = site
      @base = base
      @dir  = 'partials'
      @name = "#{post.id}.html".tr('/','')


      self.process(name)
      self.read_yaml(File.join(base, '_layouts'), "partial.html")
      self.data['page'] = post
    end
  end
end
```

The partial.html layout includes `<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>` and the generated output is `<h1></h1>`

I've tried `puts(post.title)` in the initialize method and it prints the correct titles on the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself now.

The data you put into `self.data[]`is available as property of page in the template/layout.

So `self.data[‘test'] = "..."` can be accessed through `{{page.test}}`.

Now my generator includes `self.data['page'] = post` and I access it in my partial.html as `<h1>{{page.post.title}}</h1>`.